# Incorrect format specifier with gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc

This is a simple program in C to illustrate how C allocates memory to variables. The idea is that there will be a new memory address shown each time I re-compile the program.

Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
        int a;
        int b = 10;
        float c = 5.8;

        printf("the address is %u \n", &a);
        printf("the address is %u \n", &b);
        printf("the address is &u \n", &c);

        getch();
}
```

When I run this `gcc program_name.c`, I get a series of errors:

```
program_name.c:3:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
      [-Wimplicit-int]
main()
^
program_name.c:9:33: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the
      argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("the address is %u \n", &a);
                               ~~      ^~
program_name.c:10:33: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the
      argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("the address is %u \n", &b);
                               ~~      ^~
program_name.c:11:33: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the
      argument has type 'float *' [-Wformat]
        printf("the address is %u \n", &c);
                               ~~      ^~
program_name.c:13:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getch' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        getch();
        ^
5 warnings generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

I cannot understand why these errors are being thrown. Surely `%u` is an entirely appropriate format specifier. What am I missing? How can I reformat the code to stop these errors?

EDIT: Based on the responses, it appears the correct code should be

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int a;
        int b = 10;
        float c = 5.8;

        printf("the address is %p \n", &a);
        printf("the address is %p \n", &b);
        printf("the address is %p \n", &c);

        return 0;
}
```

That does run without errors.

Comment: use `%p` instead of `%u`

Comment: And use `%p` instead of `&u` in the third format — though the error message shows that the code in the question doesn't exactly match the code the compiler was complaining about.  And `getch()` is not a standard C function.  It is available on Windows (normally declared in `<conio.h>`).  The version available on Linux/Unix requires the curses library and appropriate setup work (and is declared in `<curses.h>`, but — as I said already — you can't simply call it without initializing the library properly, and you need to link with either `-lncurses` or `-lcurses` depending on platform).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `%u` at message.

Comment: try `int main()` instead of `main`; doing so will require a return at the end of main.  try %p as your format specifier.  Try adding either `#include <conio.h>` if programming on Windows, if Linux `#include <curses.h>`; in either case you will need to link in the appropriate libraries

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: yeah — I noticed that the compiler was compiling different code.

Comment: `int main()` not just `main()`, `%p` not `%u` (as BLUEPIXY mentioned), `getch()` isn't standard (though could probably just be skipped here), and you may find that the addresses don't appear to change between compiles (they *could*, but on many systems the address you see isn't the actual physical address - each process may have its own virtual address space, and the address may stay the same within that).

Comment: "Surely %u is an entirely appropriate format specifier." is incorrect.  `"%u"` is for `unsigned`, not `int *`.  Use `"%p"`.

Comment: @Dmitri `int main (void)` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`. `int main()` is not much better than `main()` in C.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Could you explain to me the difference?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang `(void)` means the function takes no arguments, whereas `()` means the arguments aren't specified (though it might accept some).  Newer versions of the C standard require `int main(void)` if main doesn't take arguments, though in the past `int main()` was also allowed.  It's a good idea to use `(void)` rather than `()`, but depending on the compiler and the standard being used, not always strictly necessary.